# Expectation of discrete random variable is well-defined

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, expected-value

The following piece is taken from my probability textbook. We assume that $X$ takes distinct values $x_1, x_2, \dots$, and is constant on $\Lambda_1, \Lambda_2, \dots$, where $X$ might take the same value on more than one $\Lambda_i$'s. We also assume that $X$ is integrable, i.e.
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |x_i| P\{\Lambda_i \} < \infty.
$$
Our goal is to show that
$$
E\{X\} = \sum_i x_i P\{\Lambda_i\}
$$
exists. Since $X$ is constant on $\Lambda_i$, each $\Lambda_i \subset \{X = x_j\}$ for some $j$. Thus, for each $j$, we can find some subsequence $j_k$ such that $\{X=x_j\} = \bigcup_{k}\Lambda_{j_k}$, with $x_{j_k} = x_j$ for each $k$. Because of the absolute convergence above, we can rearrange the terms without changing the sum and and write
$$
\sum_i x_i P\{\Lambda_i\} = \sum_{j} \sum_k x_{j_k} P\{\Lambda_{j_k}\} = \sum_{j} x_j \sum_k P\{\Lambda_{j_k}\},
$$
since $x_{j_k}=x_j$ for each $k$.

My question is: why is the rearrangement of the terms in the the middle expression valid? Is the rearrange even a permutation of the original terms? If not, how can I justify rearrangement above?

In a permutation, every term of the sequence, say the $i^{th}$ term moves to some specific position, say $\pi(i)^{th}$ position. But here, we might encounter a countable number of terms before we can get to that $\pi(i)^{th}$ position, since a particular value may be achieved on a countable number of $\Lambda_i$'s.

Comment: The theorem reads like a special case of Lebesgue integration, where measure is defined on discrete points, i.e. absolute intergrability implies integrability.

Comment: It is just the rearrangement of absolute convergent series since $P\{\Lambda_i \}\ge 0$.  You can adapt the proof at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence#Rearrangements_and_unconditional_convergence